# Private copy of data from shared location

Tags: c#, windows, multithreading, concurrency

I'm at the moment reading `Concurrent Programming on Windows` by Joe Duffy, and came across the following statement:

> Multiple threads make private copies of data from a shared location

This statement was given after an example where Joe showed how incrementing a global variable from multiple threads could lead to unpredictable results, because they could overlap in time.

However I remain skeptic about the statement, since there's no such thing as a private copy of a atomic data type - that would make it non-atomic.

So when he says `make private copies of data from a shared location` is it then simply all non-atomic data types (user-defined types, etc.) he means, or have I missed something?

Comment: No, its all data types. The volatile keyword in c# is supposed to force threads to get the most up to date value of that variable each time it references it. http://igoro.com/archive/volatile-keyword-in-c-memory-model-explained/

Comment: @Kell, according to C# specification then `int` is atomic (both read/write). It makes no sense at all, to first move the value of a static int field into a local register of the processor the given thread use, modify the value (not increment/decrement - just a simple write), and then finally update the shared memory location with the new value. - That's not atomic, that's 3 instructions.

Comment: @Kell The `volatile` keyword means "use Release and Acquire" semantics, nothing more.  It **doesn't** mean that threads will get the most up to date value of that variable when it is referenced. See [Volatile reads and writes (Joe Duffy)](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/PermaLink,guid,dd3aff8a-7f8d-4de6-a2e7-d199662b68f4.aspx)

Comment: @Justin Yeah, I should've underline the "supposed to" part in my comment as it doesn't. Your link is a far better explanation. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I don't have the book on hands, I can only guess he's talking about how processors execute code.

There is no scape from transferring data to a CPU register because this is the only way a CPU instruction can access it. So, in this sense, every time a thread uses data from a shared location a temporary private copy has to be made.